# What is wrong with my CGContextclip.

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am beginner with Core Garphics and I am try to get around with my understanding of CGContextclip. I am doing a simple program with custom UIButton drawrect as below

Rect dimension passed to drawRect method is CustomButton *button = [[CustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];

```
@implementation CustomButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGColorRef colorRef = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colorRef);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0f);

CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
//CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor]CGColor]);

CGMutablePathRef rectPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(rectPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
CGPathAddLineToPoint(rectPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
CGPathAddLineToPoint(rectPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
CGPathAddLineToPoint(rectPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
CGPathCloseSubpath(rectPath);

CGContextAddPath(context, rectPath);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
//CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGColorRelease(colorRef);
}

@end
```

I am expecting a full rect with dimension (0,0,100,50) colored in blue and a half rect inside with red coloured. I am getting the blue colored rect but red colored rect is not visible in my context.

I have gone through some solution here and also at some blogs but to my faulty eyes the code looks simple and fine. What is wrong with my clipping.

Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no path in the context anymore after you clipped it.Just fill another rectangle:

```
//CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```